# The Spatial Data for layer... in the map... is not valid. Specify Spatial data that is data type SqlGeometry or SqlGeography. Report Builder 3.0

Tags: xml, reportbuilder, file-conversion, spatial-data

I am editing the data set for a map report programmatically in VS 2010 by changing the dataset queries in a baseline report converted to xml, then displaying the new report, converted to .rdl in Report Builder.  When Report Builder is first launched and is in design mode, the map says

"The shared data source... does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions.  for more information contact your report server administrator.  No spatial data available.  The map display contains sample spatial data."

However if I click inside the viewport, the map displays report data as specified, in design mode.  At this point when I try to run the report, I get the above error.  I do not understand how the spatial data can be invalid if it is being displayed in design mode.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it, the baseline report I was using didn't include all coordinates in my database, so when I tried to run a report that had a larger scope than my baseline, the VectorData didn't exist for some of the coordinates.